# Django inconsistent time on DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

I have next model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    _date=models.DateTimeField()
```

In views.py

-When I try this one:

```
p = People(name='foo', lastname='bar', _date=datetime.now())
p.save()
```

it returns current time: `2012-10-31 17:33:10.152323`

But, when I check my database for this record it shows:

```
name lastname _date 
foo   bar      2012-10-31 21:33:10
```

Why this(two different time) happens?

Edit: (it is 4 hours difference): `2012-10-31 17:33:10.152323  and 2012-10-31 21:33:10`

Answer (score 2):

Django uses timezones to store `DatetimeFields` into your database. This is why you supplied a `TIME_ZONE` in your settings.

You can read more about this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

If you want to supply your fields with a non naive datetime, you have to use:

```
now = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone('Your/Timezone'))
```

Timezones can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name

Comment: I tried but I got this error: 'type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'time zone''

Comment: I also replaced with TIME_ZONE = 'US/East-Indiana' in setting.py, but it does not change anything

Comment: you'll have to import timezone with: from pytz import timezone

Comment: It will have the same effect with replacing 'TIME_ZONE' in settings, right? So, even though I replaced the time zone with my time zone still I am getting wrong time Why?

Comment: no. you you supply a timezone for your app in settings to tell django your current timezone. To create a date in your timezone, you'll have to use the code posted above. This is because every timezone is represented as an offset of UTC. In Your case in East-Indiana: -4.

Comment: Ok, I tried it, but it seems something wrong again results: when I print the time it returns: 2012-11-01 00:36:58.412188-05:00 and database record is 2012-11-01 05:36:58. My time is right now 2012-11-01 20:36:58

Answer (score 1):

Even I was facing the same issue. This is because according to the django documentation

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

Solution to this problem is writing a function that converts time stored in database to your local time.

```
from django.utils import timezone
import pytz

def get_localtime(utctime):
    utc = utctime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    localtz = utc.astimezone(timezone.get_current_timezone())
    return localtz
```

Now you can

```
now = get_localtime(datetime.now())
p = People(name='foo', lastname='bar', _date=now)
p.save()
```